# How do you solve the issue of emotional detachment when using unreliable narration?

Tags: creative-writing, narrative, narrator

I've been told that unreliable narration can cause emotional detachment because the reader may not trust or empathize with the narrator's perspective, which can make it hard to connect with the characters or become invested in their story.

For example, in the novel *Gone Girl* by Gillian Flynn, the narrator Amy Dunne is revealed to be an unreliable narrator. As the story progresses, it becomes clear that she has manipulated events and lied to the reader about her actions and motivations. This can make it challenging for the reader to sympathize with her or connect with her on an emotional level, leading to emotional detachment.

How do you solve this issue of emotional detachment in a story like *Gone Girl*?